# extern vector created in constructor

Tags: c++, vector

I have a class Team and a class Ball and I create a vector in constructor of Team that is filled with objects of another class called Player. So I want to use this vector in the class Ball but even though I define it as extern (public) compiler keeps telling me that I have undefined reference to team that is my vector. Here follows the code of Team.cpp and Ball.cpp
**Team.h**

```
#define TEAM_H
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Player.h"

using namespace std; 
extern vector<Player> team; 
class Team {
    public:
        Team();

        void fillTeamVector(vector<Player>&);

    private:
        string teamName;
        int faults;
        int passes;
        int goals;

};

#endif // TEAM_H
```

**Team.cpp**

```
#include "Team.h"
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "Player.h"
#include "Attacker.h"
#include "Defender.h"
#include "Ball.h"

Team::Team()
{
    extern vector<Player> team;
    fillTeamVector(team);
}

void Team::fillTeamVector(vector<Player>& team){

// do stuff and store them on vector team
}
```

And here follows the code for **Ball.h** note that I commented all the methods that don't affect the problem.

```
#ifndef BALL_H
#define BALL_H
#include "Player.h"

class Ball
{
    public:
        Ball();
        Player* current;
        Player* previous;

        /*void setX_ball(int);
        int getX_ball() const;
        void setY_ball(int);
        int getY_ball() const;*/
        void assign();
        //void changeCurrentToPrevious();
        //void changeNextToCurrent(Player*);


    private:
        int X_ball;
        int Y_ball;
};

#endif // BALL_H
```

Here is the code for **Ball.cpp** note that in method assign if I create a new (and obviously different vector of Player named team it will compile correctly)

```
#include "Ball.h"
#include "Team.h"
#include "Player.h"

extern vector<Player> team;

Ball::Ball()
:   X_ball(2),
    Y_ball(5)
{
    current = NULL;
    previous = NULL;

}

void Ball::assign(){
    //vector<Player> team;
    int x;
    int y;
    x=(team[0].getX())-X_ball;
    y=(team[0].getY())-Y_ball;
    int min=x+y;
    int k=0;
    for (int i=1; i<team.size(); i++){
        x=(team[i].getX())-X_ball;
        y=(team[i].getY())-Y_ball;
        int sum=x+y;
        if(sum<min){
            k=i;
        }
    }
    current = &team[k];
}
```

Comment: You just keep on *declaring* the vector variable, but you never actually *define* it anywhere.

Comment: Even if I type extern<Player> team; on public of Team.h it produces the same error

Comment: @GerasimosRagavanis -- Do you know how to declare and define global variables in a multi-module program?  That's the issue -- it has nothing to do with `vector`.  Change it to `int`, and you still would have the same problem.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `vector`.  You have not defined your variable anywhere in your code.  You've `extern`ed it to death, but nowhere in one (and only one) module do you have `vector<Player> team;` without the `extern`.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and your patience. I think this will solve my problem.

Comment: Using a static class member of Team would be better than this extern vector

Comment: can you explain it a little bit further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing

```
extern vector<Player> team;
```

you only *declare* the variable.

In one source file you must actually *define* the variable:

```
vector<Player> team;
```

Note the lack of `extern` in the definition.

Also note that this has to be done in the *global* scope, since you want a global variable. So it has to be defined outside of any functions or classes or namespaces.

Comment: @GerasimosRagavanis If you do it inside a function, then you define a *local* variable. You need to define the variable in the *global* scope, outside of any functions.

Comment: @GerasimosRagavanis No, you should declare it as a *member variable* inside the class.